# How to use a variable to name a Powerpoint slide using VBA rather than a literal string

Tags: vba, powerpoint-2010

I am trying to create a new slide and name it at the same time using VBA.  I have a main menu page that contains shapes with text labels in them.  I've set the action for each shape to run the following macro:  It is intended to create a new slide and name it the same as the category name that is shown in text on the button the user clicked.

```
Sub ChangeSlideName(objCurrentShape As Shape) ' Place the clicked on shape in a variable.

    Dim objTextInBox As String
    Dim objCurrentSlideNum As Integer
    
' Place current slide number into a variable.
    objCurrentSlideNum = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.CurrentShowPosition
    
' Set value of string variable to the text in the shape clicked on.
    objTextInBox = ActivePresentation.Slides(objCurrentSlideNum).Shapes(objCurrentShape.Name).TextFrame.TextRange.Text
    
' Create a new slide at the end of the presentation.
    Set pptNewSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides.Add(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutBlank)
    
' Make the new slide the active slide.
    ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Last
    
' Set the name of the new slide to the text contained on the button clicked.
    ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Name = objTextInBox
    
End Sub
```

My code runs and takes me to the newly created slide; however, I don't know how to tell if it actually named the new slide.  Because I'm using a variable to name the slide, I suspect it isn't working.  When I run another macro from a different slide, it will not jump me to the slide I renamed.  I also use a variable to identify the name of the slide I am trying to jump to.  I've tried all 4 of the following commands one at a time.

```
' Take user to the page of the category clicked on.
    SlideShowWindows(1).View.GotoSlide GetSlideIndex(objTextInBox)
    
    ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.GotoSlide (objTextInBox)
    
    SlideShowWindows(1).View.GotoSlide GetSlideIndex(objTextInBox), 1
    
    ActivePresentation.Slides(objTextInBox).Select
```

Am I missing something in my code like parenthesis or quotation marks or something?  Can I not use a variable in place of a literal string like "New Slide Name"?  Also, can someone tell me how to verify the name of a slide?

Comment: This is VBA, a different language than VBScript. You should change the tag form VBS to VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These work for Powerpoint-2010.  I haven't tried it in other version.
When a user clicks on a shape (in my case it's a rectangle with text inside that shows a category name) this code will create a new slide and name it whatever category name was in the shape clicked on.

```
Sub ChangeSlideName(objClickedShape As Shape) ' Place the clicked on shape in a variable.

    Dim objText As String
    Dim objSlideNum As Integer
    Dim pptNewSlide

    
' Place current slide number into a variable.
    objSlideNum = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.CurrentShowPosition
    
' Set value of string variable to the text in the shape clicked on.
    objText = ActivePresentation.Slides(objSlideNum).Shapes(objClickedShape.Name).TextFrame.TextRange.Text
    
' Create a new slide at the end of the presentation.
    Set pptNewSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides.Add(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutBlank)
    
' Make the new slide the active slide.
    ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Last
    
' Change slide # variable to the number of the newly created slide.
    objSlideNum = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.CurrentShowPosition
    
' Set the name of the new slide to the text contained on the button clicked.
    ActivePresentation.Slides(objSlideNum).Name = objText
 
End Sub
```

This is the command that will jump to the newly created slide using the variable:

```
    Dim osld As Slide
    Set osld = ActivePresentation.Slides(objTextInBox)
    SlideShowWindows(1).View.GotoSlide (osld.SlideIndex)
```

This allows me to use one macro to jump between slides by using the slide names as the text written in the shapes in the presentation.